# How to create a dataframe of one index of a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-xarray

I have a dataset `NearGrid` with dimensions (index:225, time:25933) that contains daily temperature data for 225 locations.
[image]
How can I create a dataframe for the first location (index=0) where the columns are date and tmax and each row represents one day of data (i.e. 25933 rows x 2 columns)?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
#import libraries
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

#open netcdf files
df=xr.open_mfdataset('/glacier1/mmartin/data/NOAATmax/Tmax****.nc')

#open cm stations csv and create new dataset with only points closest to stations in CMStations
CMStations=pd.read_csv('Slope95.csv')
Lat=CMStations.lat
Lon=CMStations.lon
NearGrid=df.sel(lat=Lat.to_xarray(), lon=Lon.to_xarray(), method='nearest')

#create dataframe of first location in NearGrid
NearGrid.isel(index=0).to_dataframe()
```

but when I do this the code runs indefinitely and nothing happens.

Comment: It would definitely be helpful to know where the code is stuck. I expect it's probably at the xr.open_mfdataset stage. If you stop the process with Ctrl+C can you get a traceback which helps identify which line is currently running? if your data is indexed by `(index, time)` you shouldn't be able to select using lat/lon - you can only select with index or time. Find the station which is closest to the lat/lon values using geopandas or just minimizing squared distance. Your to_dataframe code should work fine, but I expect you're running into trouble earlier?

Comment: Also FWIW your data is chunked in a way that will make this a pretty slow op, since each chunk includes a small subset of times but all stations. Since it's a pretty small array to begin with (23MB) you might have better luck just loading all the data at the start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the way the data was chunked. When I saved the subsetted data as a new netcdf file and then opened it in a new notebook, it worked. I did that through this:

```
#import libraries
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

#open netcdf files
df=xr.open_mfdataset('/glacier1/mmartin/data/NOAATmax/Tmax****.nc')

#open cm stations csv and create new dataset with only points closest to stations in CMStations
CMStations=pd.read_csv('Slope95.csv')
Lat=CMStations.lat
Lon=CMStations.lon
NearGrid=df.sel(lat=Lat.to_xarray(), lon=Lon.to_xarray(), method='nearest')

#save as new netcdf file
NearGrid.to_netcdf('/glacier1/mmartin/data/NOAATmax/Tmax_CMStations_19510101-20211231.nc')
```

I then opened this file in a new notebook and manipulated the data there